# What determines which platter/sector a HDD writes to?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

How does a HDD determine which platter/sector to use? Is there a controller built into the drive itself? Or is it the motherboard? The OS?

What kind of algorithm chooses this? Surely it can't be random nor can it be sequential.

Similarly, how do the same questions apply to an SSD?

Comment: " Is there a controller built into the drive itself?" Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does a HDD determine which platter/sector to use?

> What kind of algorithm chooses this? Surely it can't be random nor can it be sequential.

That is proprietary information that you'd be unlikely to find. A "*trade secret*" or "*secret sauce*" if you will...

There is no "*shallow*" reason for it to not be random or sequential... but I suspect disk manufacturers will optimise data throughput by placing data across all platters. There will very likely be a "*deep*" reason for placing the data where they do (modern hard disks are approaching the realms of magic, with huge technical knowledge required to understand most of what's going on).

Historically it was open and well understood (see [CHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector), below).

> Is there a controller built into the drive itself?

Yes - a modern hard disk will present a [SATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA) or [SAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Attached_SCSI) interface to the host machine... This communication link runs between the motherboard and the hard disk's onboard controller.

The controller is subsequently responsible for managing the spindle speed, head position, processing between read/write instructions and the precisely timed analog signals to/from the read/write heads, etc...

> Or is it the motherboard? The OS?

Historically, the hard disk presented as a very raw device - a stepper motor or voice coil was driven directly from the motherboard to manage the head positions, and the analog signals were crudely cleaned before being transmitted to the motherboard.

See this [video teardown of a Fujitsu 337 MB 8inch hard disk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7k5ecRZeaw) for the gory details. Skip to ~2:04 for a run down of the interfaces ([Storage Module Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_Module_Device)). Even so, as you can see, there is considerable support circuitry for interfacing.

Hard disks were addressed using [CHS (Cylinder - Head - Sector)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector), but more recently they are addressed using [LBA (Logical Block Addressing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing).

I *think* that with the introduction of LBA, we also started seeing disks that managed their own bad sectors - relocating them into provisioned "*spare*" space when they were detected to be bad. So we no longer have direct control of where the heads are positioned, which head is used, and which sector is accessed.

Before disks managed their own bad sectors, you'd see labels with a list of bad sectors from the factory, that you had to feed into the system while creating the filesystem. Alternatively you'd use a tool like [`badblocks`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badblocks) to scan for issues. For example:

[image: bad sector list]

> Similarly, how do the same questions apply to an SSD?

With an SSD the entire flash storage is mapped from the physical to virtual address space. This allows for [wear-levelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling) to be implemented transparently without *any* knowledge from the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

What determines which platter/sector a HDD writes to?

The individual algorithms and instructions contained in the hard drive controlled determines the location of most data sent to HDDs.

With spinning HDDs the OS can access all possible addresses on the drive and CAN specify a specific location to read or write.

With SSDs the controller virtualizes the actual addresses in order to support some of the advanced features SSDs offer, such as over-provisioning and the ability to find and mark bad bits and black-list them without actually shrinking, as well as caching and other things, so the OS does not typically know the real possible addresses in an SSD.